# Deploying scala and java springboot project on ubuntu server

Tags: java, scala, tomcat

My question is about deploying a project written in scala and java with springboot as backend. First I tried to build it with IDEA as .war file and put it under

> my-tomcat-dir/webapps/

on my Ubuntu 18.04 server. When I run it with

> sh my-tomcat-dir/bin/catalina.sh run

it just seems well, however it didn't respond to any request from my frontend application and there is no any errors log in my terminal screen. So I tried to build the project on my Ubuntu server. First I upload my project files to the server and run

> sbt assembly

in the project directory, later I run

> sbt package

and got a .war file. Again I put the file under

> my-tomcat-dir/webapps/

and it just got the same result as before. How can I get this project built and run well under this situation? Any further information please inform me to provide, thanks!

Comment: if the war is a springboot application then try if the springbood actuator responds

Comment: @ValentinCarnu No response from springboot actuator, so I couldn't figure out what's happening.

Comment: check tomcat's localhost log file maybe there are some details there